# RxJS v7: How to dynamically add/remove and pause/resume observables?

Tags: rxjs

Given some arrays:

```
const recordings = {
  foo: [{delay: 5, data: 'a'}, {delay: 2, data: 'b'}],
  bar: [{delay: 3, data: 'x'}, {delay: 7, data: 'y'}, {delay: 4, data: 'z'}]
};
```

Is there a way that I can pass them to a playback method that will do something like the following?:

```
beginPlayback(timeline, fromIndex = 0) {
  let postedIndex = -1;
  const observable = from(timeline.slice(fromIndex)).pipe(
    concatMap((instant, i) => of({ i, instant }).pipe(delay(instant.delay))),
    tap(async ({i, instant}) => {
      try {
        await post(instant.data);
        postedIndex = i;
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        // Continue playback
      }
    })
  );

  const handle = {
    postedIndex,
    subscription: observable.subscribe()
  };
  return handle;
}
```

...and then allow me to manage concurrent playback with an external/public interface like this?:

```
const handles = {};
const paused = {};

onAddNewRecordingRequest(id, timeline) {
  recordings[id] = timeline;
}

onBeginPlaybackRequest(id) {
  handles[id] = beginPlayback(recordings[id]);
}

onPauseRequested(id) {
  const handle = handles[id];
  paused[id] = handle.postedIndex;
  handle.subscription.unsubscribe() // dispose of observable
}

onResumeRequested(id) {
  const alreadyThroughIndex = paused[id];
  handles[id] = beginPlayback(recordings[id], alreadyThroughIndex);
  delete paused[id];
}

onStopRequested(id) {
  const handle = handles[id];
  handle.subscription.unsubscribe() // dispose of observable
}
```

Is there also a way to automatically remove the observable and the handle when the observable is completed?

Comment: Yes, that's all possible

Comment: @MrkSef,  I think the main thing I'm looking for is a way to both detect the completion of an observable (ideally as a promise) and be able to pause or cancel it e.g., by unsubscribing. Would you kindly point me to an article or portion of the RxJs API that seems like it would be useful to these ends?

Comment: `toPromise` only resolves once the observable completes, (or errors). [link](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise). Also, you seem aware of how to unsubscribe, but a lot of operators deal with that as well. You can google **"RxJS unsubscribe"** and you're sure to find articles discussing those. :)

Comment: I would recommend giving it a try and asking questions specific to a problem you've encountered. RxJS is a pretty expressive library, so the answer to "can it do x?" is almost certainly yes.